# Ubuntu 20.10 doesn't suspend when lid closed and additional monitor is connected

Tags: suspend

Recently I switched to Ubuntu 20.10 and I observed that when I close the lid normally computer suspends. However, if I connect additional monitor (model HP 24f), it doesn't suspend, even screen doesn't get locked.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour even though it is annoying. When you have an external monitor connected, you might want to close the lid and continue working with just the external monitor.
A workaround is suspending manually before closing the lid.